# Probability HW question

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose someone receives 12 texts per hour.

What is the probability that this person received more than 4 texts in 10 minutes?

I'm clueless about how to start this. I know i have to use random variables and possibly cdf, but not how.

Comment: To solve this problem, we would need to know the probability distribution of text receiving. I'm guessing it's Poisson with $\lambda=12$.

Comment: The problem doesn't mention the distribution. I guess that's why i'm clueless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X\sim Po(\frac{12}{6})=X\sim Po(2)$
P$(X>4) =$ $1-$P$(X\leq4)=1-0.9473=0.0527$

Comment: Thanks. But what justifies the poisson dist?

Comment: Without context, just a guess based on similar probability problems.(+1) In context, it would be a good bet you've studied Poisson distributions recently. Notice the importance of adapting the Poisson rate to the _specific question_ asked. Rate is 12/hr (_on average!_), but question is about 10 min, and rate is 2 per 10 min.

Comment: thanks for answering his question.